# How do I connect to a MySQL server with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to connect to my MySQL server with PHP but I keep getting "Failed to get results." on my webpage. This is the code I'm using.

```html
<?PHP
 error_reporting(1);
 
 //Connect to MySQL server.
 $mysqli = new MySQLi('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'login') or die(mysql_error());
 
 //Query the database.
 $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM users");
 
 //Count the returned rows.
 if($result->num_rows != 0){
  //Convert query into array.
  while($rows = $result->fetch_asocc()) {
   $id = $rows['ID'];
   $username = $rows['Username'];
   $email = $rows['Email'];
   $password = $rows['Password'];
   
   //Display results.
   echo "ID: $id\nUsername: $username\nE-Mail: $email\nPassword: $password\n";
  }
 } else {
  echo "Failed to get results.";
 }
 
?>
```

Comment: Mixing `mysql and mysqli in your code` at `$mysqli = new MySQLi('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'login') or die(mysql_error());
`

Comment: `echo $mysqli->error;` in a couple places and see if it prints errors.

Comment: @Saty Although it's a bad idea to do that, it shouldn't be the reason for the code not working.

Comment: I just pointing `or die(mysql_error());` line of code to indicate what wrong with this script @Matt

Comment: what happens when you `var_dump($result->num_rows))` ?

Comment: I am not sure it may be `new mysqli(..)` instead `new MySQLi(...)`

Comment: i'm not sure but isn't mysqli should be in lower case ? `$mysqli = new mysqli(...`

Comment: Use lowercase `mysqli`

Comment: I used lowercase and it doesn't say "Failed to get results." but it won't echo the code under the comment //Display results.

Comment: And I tried to use var_dump($result->num_rows); but it didn't do anything.

Comment: I'm back at where I started it says "Failed to get results." again. This is what I changed `$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'gigajneo', 'yJmL9R_mE6UjU', 'login') or die($mysqli->error);`